# how to write float values with decimal points in c++

Tags: c++

I want to know that how to write float values with decimal points in c++. Here,  I want to print decimal point value. Here is the program: This program gives output with floating numbers but in answer there is first value  it prints  is 1 and i want 1.000000.All the other values are coming with 6 decimal points. Only there is issue with first value. Though i have use cout.precision but still it will not give me the correct output. I also don't want to use setw() for this. Thank in advance.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    float x,y;
    clrscr();
    cout<<" TABLE FOR Y=EXP(-X) :\n\n";
    cout<<"x";
    for(float k=0;k<0.9;k=k+0.1)
    cout<<"\t  "<<k;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"---------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout<<"\n";
    for(float j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        cout<<j;
        for(float i=0;i<.8;i=i+0.1)
        {
            x=i+j;
            y=exp(-x);
            cout.precision(6);
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout<<"  "<<y;
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you expect that to work? Integer values are integer values, they don't have any decimals. If you want to print a value with decimals then you need to use floating point values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT]

In your code you print j the first time before using `cout.precision(6);`, also it's useless set the precision every time, try this:

```
cout.precision(6);
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
for(float j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    cout<<j;
    for(float i=0;i<0.8;i=i+0.1)
    {
        x=i+j;
        y=exp(-x);
        cout<<"  "<<y;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

[OLD]

You can convert your variable to float in the cout:

```
void main()
{  
  int a = 1;
  std::cout.precision(2);
  std::cout << std::fixed << static_cast<float>(a) << std::endl;
}
```

The result will be: 1.00

Comment: Personally I would advice against using C-style casting here, and instead use `static_cast<float>(a)` instead.

Comment: There is no "cout function"; `std::cout` is an object, and you pass it to various functions, usually stream inserters, which are overloads of `operator<<`.

Comment: I corrected the answer with both your suggestions.I know that cout isn't a function, it was a typing error. I was writing something else